# Is it possible to run NetBeans installed in Windows to run on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems, netbeans

My system was running on windows 8. Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 13.10 to my system without removing windows. Due to some problems now I can't boot Windows. But Ubuntu is working fine. I was doing a project in windows using NetBeans IDE. Since I cannot boot Windows I can't do my project. Is it possible to use NetBeans in Ubuntu, that was installed in Windows ? Or, is there any tools to do this ?

Comment: Ubuntu is unable to run Windows programs at least not without something like http://www.winehq.org

Comment: @Ramhound Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: I just told you there is.  You have to use Wine.  But you would have to transfer the prject from your Windows installation yourself.  Far easier to fix your Windows installation.

Comment: Easier still to install a ubuntu version of netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NetBeans IDE is available for various platforms, including Windows and Linux. Just install NetBeans for Linux, either from Ubuntu's package manager (it is located in the *universe* category) or from [netbeans.org](http://netbeans.org).